# Connect to database in GWT and strange errors

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to estabilish connection to oracle database in GWT (server side) and this is my code:

client side:

package com.db.client;

```
 import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
 import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
 import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class Db_connection implements EntryPoint {

private final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT
        .create(GreetingService.class);

/**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */

public void onModuleLoad() {
    greetingService.greetServer(new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            System.out.println("FAILED");
        }

        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    });
}
}
```

interfaces (client side):

```
package com.db.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

/**
 * The client side stub for the RPC service.
 */
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
        String greetServer() throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

and:

```
package com.db.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

/**
 * The async counterpart of <code>GreetingService</code>.
 */
public interface GreetingServiceAsync {
    void greetServer(AsyncCallback<String> callback)
            throws IllegalArgumentException;
}}
```

and server side:

```
package com.db.server;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.db.client.GreetingService;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;

public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        GreetingService {

    public String greetServer() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String date = "data";

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe", "test", "test");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            try {
                ResultSet rset = stmt
                        .executeQuery("select BANNER from SYS.V_$VERSION");
                try {
                    while (rset.next())
                        date = (rset.getString(1)); // Print col 1
                } finally {
                    try {
                        rset.close();
                    } catch (Exception ignore) {
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (Exception ignore) {
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }

        return date;
    }

}
```

and stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:320)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:199)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:195)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.db.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:370)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
2012-09-01 13:16:24 com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.db.client.GreetingService.greetServer() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission localhost resolve)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:370)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission localhost resolve)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:283)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.resolver.HostnameNamingAdapter.resolve(HostnameNamingAdapter.java:167)
    at oracle.net.resolver.NameResolver.resolveName(NameResolver.java:133)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:416)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:687)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:247)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.db.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 34 more
```

what i'm doing wrong? 
Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable App Engine in your project if you're not going to deploy your application there.

Comment: Yes, it works, but in addition you need to move up GWT SDK above GAE in Java Build Path.

Comment: How to disable app engine?